# Remove the duplicate limit

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

The new duplicate functionality is great, but it's limited to a total of five "originals" per question. :(

[image: only five]

Can the limit be removed, or at least increased?

[image: more]

Comment: [What???](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Pp9nUrvU_Yk/hqdefault.jpg)

Comment: Is it really useful to have 5+ duplicate targets? If the first five don't answer the question, it's probably not a duplicate..

Comment: @Rob - They do answer the question... but they're not the only ones to do so.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Okay, but is there any *benefit* to adding so many duplicate targets? Why not close some of the targets themselves as duplicate. The whole point of closing as duplicate is to consolidate information.

Comment: I'll bite... why? If each of the duplicate targets answers the question, who cares if we collectively identify *every* question on the site with an answer that answers the question? Nobody really wants to scroll through a list of 100 duplicate targets for some question about a syntax error, especially if 1 is enough.

Comment: I guess I'll leave it at 5, and put extras in a comment. =\

Comment: Agent smith everywhere!

Comment: We could add a link to a search query that will show what the OP should have done in the first place (I suppose, that’s the actual point of wanting to include all of them into the list of duplicates)…

Answer (score 21):

I'm confused.

One duplicate should be enough to cover the *general* question, but *five* seems like overkill.  It looks like you're just piling on more and more "duplicate" questions.

My gut feeling on this feature is that it's meant to help resolve issues in which a gold-badge holder believes that a *better* duplicate exists, rather than to pile on a ton of, "here, go read this" links instead.  Having two or three is nice to have, but from what I can see in the titles alone, at least two of those duplicates shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 13):

No.

If more than couple distinct duplicates needed to cover the question it likely means the question should be either edited to be more concrete or closed as too broad instead.

If all duplicates are similar instead of adding a list of duplicates they should be organized and likely closed as duplicates of one of the question in the list.