# Badge for closing own question as duplicate

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

I believe that [having a question closed as duplicate is not a bad thing](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). When hinted, one could be happy to mark and close their own question as duplicate: it means that they just found a solution.

Could we maybe incentivize and advertise those who do so with a badge?

Comment: I think that the result would be users running to post duplicate questions to self-close;  just to get the badge.

Comment: @yivi - there are plenty of Bronze badges that are simple to earn and easily gamed (Peer Pressure is a great example).  They exist to just teach people about the features of site.  This would be a good way to show users that (1) they can vote to close their own questions as duplicates, and (2) duplicates are not a bad thing on their own

Comment: But badges are there to incentivize desirable behavior. While dupes are not necessarily a bad thing, I do not think intentionally posting dupes is a desirable thing; and I believe that would be the result of a badge like this one.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361371/how-many-duplicates-if-any-are-enough-to-justify-deletion-of-a-question

Comment: @yivi intentionally asking a bad question to get downvotes just to delete it is no different - in fact, I think it is worse.  Many of the basic badges can be abused easier.  `Suffrage` encourage people to use all of their votes just to get a badge.  `Excavator` encourages people to make a random edit to an old post.  I could go on.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I see your point, but I disagree. Deleting bad content is a desirable behavior. Voting is a desirable behavior. An accepted edit of old content is a desirable behavior. I see no benefit in having this badge, and enough possible downsides. I guess it could be tweaked to be slightly better, but frankly I do not see the allure. Just my opinion, though. It may be that our SO overlords fall in love with the idea. :)

Comment: @psubsee2003 So why add *yet another* badge that encourages people to engage in bad behavior?  The fact that we have some badges already that cause problems isn't a reason to add more.

Comment: @yivi I just happen to disagree that closing your own question is not a positive action.  It encourages people to continue their on research rather than waiting for a spoon fed answer.  A user hits a road block and asks a question, then while waiting for an answer, they find another similar SO question and realize it is a duplicate, so the vote to close their own question.  That is definately desireable

Comment: @yivi from the linked post: "I have learned to stop worrying and love (some) duplication [...] What we want is on the order of 4 or 5 similar-but-not-quite-the-same duplicates to cover all possible search terms and common permutations of the question"

Comment: @psubsee2003 More often than not, deleting their question would be a much better outcome.

Comment: @yivi depends.  Just like the related question you linked, if the question adds to the site by making the dup easier to find then it shouldn't be deleted

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, if someone has posted a good question, and later finds a duplicate, and their question is a good useful signpost to the duplicate, we want them to close the question as a duplicate.  But there are numerous problems.  First of which is that, as mentioned, people will *create bad duplicates just to close them*.  Next, most duplicates simply *aren't* useful signposts to the canonical, because they're no more discoverable than the canonical (or other existing dups).  As a result the number of duplicates worth keeping around tends to be small.

Comment: Regarding the peer pressure example as an existing badge that encourages bad behavior, I've always regarded that badge as an evidence that a person has made a really bad question/answer and then deleted it, which to me would be a badge of shame. I've seen people arguing the opposite, explaining how it's a good thing, but I've always felt that I'd be embarrassed to have that badge. Not something I would try to earn by making an intentionally bad question. I fail to understand why badge hunters would ever try to get that badge, but that's just me.

Comment: @yiwi however, making a post that is downvoted to -3 is not desirable behavior *either*, but we reward self-deleting such a post as badge-worthy (and, oddly enough, potentially post-ban-worthy as well). If that is badge-worthy, why would it not be good to reward persons who have posted dupes with a badge for realizing this and self-dupe voting?

Comment: @RobertColumbia: 1) deleting such a post is a good thing (might not be great for the poster, but it is good for the site), 2) the existing of a bad badge is not a good enough reason for another bad badge.

Answer (score 6):

Summarizing my comments above:

### No, I think this is a very bad idea

A badge like this could incentivize users posting dupes *intentionally*. We already have enough dupes, thanks.

While duplicates are not necessarily bad, their usefulness decreases as their number goes up. Posting duplicate content is very far from something we'd like to encourage, which is the stated purpose of our existing badges.

More often than not, we'd like users to *delete* their questions when they realize that their question already have an answer. While some dupes are good, the majority are just silly (having had posted and deleted a few myself).

In the end, a badge like this would just create additional posts to delete, and very, very few to actually preserve.

It is possible that with some tweaks (e.g. considering the votes the question got, if it has or if it doesn't have answers, etc, etc) this could be made *slightly* better; I still think that in the end would be a bad badge, and the purported teaching would not be enough to balance the possible downsides.

Comment: Your opinion seems to prevail in the comments and while disagreeing (I think that duplicate posts may be one of the reasons for the succces of this site), I can accept that. I didn't think about such misuse because I assumed that badge hunters went after precious badges and wouldn't do stupid things for a bronze one.

Comment: While I respect the fact that I am in the minority in my opinion of this idea, I do need to contest your "which is the stated purpose of our existing badges." wording.  The stated purpose is actually to incentivize desirable behavior or teach users about features of the site.  So this one could fall into the latter category

Comment: @psubsee2003 Sure, at the cost of incentivizing undesirable behavior, which is quite a big cost just to make people aware of the existence of duplicates, which is something I don't even think we need this badge to accomplish.