# When should a debugging question be closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48868148/2296441) was closed as a duplicate.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BsYt.png) of the question for sub-10k users.

This is strange to me because the referenced duplicates do not appear to me to be the same question. The gold badge holder who closed it indicated that, because the code has so many problems, it should be closed as a duplicate of each question that asks about the individual problems, and then re-opened when all those problems are resolved.

This does not seem correct to me.

It is either a bad question because it is too specific to apply to anyone else, or it is a good question and not a dupe despite the other issues in the code.

I am starting to lean toward the first as this question is taking a long time and lots of comments (that should be a chat) to resolve.

Comment: It is annoying as an obvious no-effort question which *happens to contain* a recognizable phrase gets closed as ... a duplicate of a perfectly well asked question.

Comment: Closing it as unclear needs 5 close voters, dupe hammering only one, so that might be a win. Due to it being closed as a dupe doesn't let roomba for 30 days, so that might be a negative effect.

Comment: ***Strongly*** related:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344972/1079354

Comment: But with the attention this post will now get due to the meta effect, it will probably get enough delete-votes.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  I'm really not sure that's a smart use of the "Delete" functionality here.  Skimming at the question [and doing my best not to break out into a rash for the sake of PHP], I don't really see how "what does this error mean in PHP" even remotely *applies* given that the OP themselves said they observed no errors.

Comment: All the extra duplicates were added after I mentioned that the first referenced duplicate probably wasn't a valid duplicate. So the gold badge user just piled on extra duplicate references that really aren't duplicate questions, but side issues that exist in the question. Last I checked, the current direction of the comment chat will not find an answer in any of the referenced duplicates.

Comment: I really don't know what users are supposed to do when faced with a large number of different errors in one post.  SO users should not be misused as incremental rewrite/test/debug drones.  I would close it as 'Too broad'.

Comment: The question (in question) has been deleted already.  Please tell us the gist of the question.  If it was another question that basically boiled down to "Why am I not getting synchronous values out of an asynchronous function?", I am all for it being closed no matter how far away from the dupe target.

Comment: @zero298 fullpage screenshot added to the question for sub-10k users to see.

Answer (score 11):

Gold-hammer as duplicate is ok and is a nicer choice.

I see following options for such posts (as I'm gold-hammer holder for C#)

- Close as duplicate of either most obvious problem or whatever OP actually trying to do. Takes one person, provides some useful info to OP and effectively limits downvotes to couple at most.
- Downvote for no effort and close as "no MCVE". As I have no expectation that OP would actually try to create MCVE, it is essentially downvote into oblivion and close at the end (if enough people care to vote - need 5).
- Spend half an hour reading and rewriting the post for OP, adding good MCVE and possibly asking multiple separate questions or linking duplicates inline with good explanation why they did not work for OP. Really ideal to make SO better, but at that point asking new question with same details would be better choice. Note that such editing is way outside of editing guidelines and is even more questionable than duplicate closure.

I prefer hammer-duplicate (sometimes with comment) as I feel this is nicer and less expensive option even if it could be slightly less appropriate close reason.

Answer (score 8):

> When should a debugging question be closed as a duplicate?

When they are effectively asking for the same thing and both are well received questions?

I really have a very hard time figuring out why someone would choose a duplicate over the close reasons for anything. If the duplicate is an off topic question, then the target is also an off topic question; if the duplicate is unclear, then the target is also unclear; and like that for every single close reason, because, duplicate means that "[t]his question **has been asked before**".

We all get annoyed when we close a question and the asker (or anyone) complains why is *this* question closed, when *that* question hasn't been closed. I don't see why the explanation for this situation doesn't apply here.

Remember:

> What we want is on the order of 4 or 5 similar-but-not-quite-the-same duplicates **to cover all possible search terms and common permutations of the question**

Having a question marked as duplicated of an unrelated question is a disservice for that goal. The objective of duplicates is to enrich the corpus of terms that would allow people to find the question they are looking for, no as a short hand to point out useful links... for that there are comments!

Comment: Being closed as duplicate doesn’t prevent a question from getting downvoted and deleted.

Comment: @Holger who will do those actions once the question is out of the way? The one that voted as duplicated? Would it wait 2 days to do so?

Comment: The same people who do that when the question was not closed or closed for a different reasons.

Comment: To put some context to @Holger comment: [as 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/296609/7), 1.6% of all deleted post where due 3rd party votes (aka vote to delete), compared with the ~40% of the community (aka roomba) and 21% of self deletion, they are insignificant.

Comment: @Braiam a closed (whatever reason) and downvoted question is a huge incentive for an OP to self-delete.

Comment: @Braiam the percentages listed there are percentages of *all posts*, not only questions. So according to that table more than 32% of all questions are deleted by their author, which includes those which got closed and downvoted first.

Comment: @Holger Are you serious? I used the percentages since whenever or not you include answers it will lead to the same conclusion: **delete votes are minority overall**.

Comment: @Shadow and? There are huge incentives to ask a good question, yet most people doesn't do it.

Comment: @Braiam since your reasoning is about *closing questions for a different reason than duplicate*, you should consider that there are significantly more questions deleted by their author than roomba has deleted closed questions. I really hope, you are not suggesting that we should never close poor questions, just because the stat says that roomba has deleted significantly more unclosed questions.

Comment: I didn't read it as Braiam suggesting not closing them, only, he's suggesting closing them for the most appropriate reason. I tend to agree with that.